# BlueCove failing to associate with Bluetooth device in Java

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I am getting the following error when i try to use a blue tooth dongle to transfer a video file from pc to mobile phone. does anyone know

```
 run:
    BlueCove log redirected to log4j
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.intel.bluetooth).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    BlueCove version 2.1.0 on bluesoleil
    java.io.IOException: Device not discovered
    BlueCove stack shutdown completed
            at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueSoleil.connectionRfOpenClientConnection(BluetoothStackBlueSoleil.java:361)
            at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.<init>(BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.java:37)
            at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openImpl(MicroeditionConnector.java:379)
            at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.open(MicroeditionConnector.java:162)
            at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:83)
            at de.avetana.obexsolo.OBEXConnector.open(OBEXConnector.java:103)
            at OBEXTest.main(OBEXTest.java:23)
```

Comment: what software are you using / is this your own software?

Comment: Look through the association of the software.

Comment: @ Andrew Bolster it is my software.

Comment: Just by-the-by, try and use more descriptive titles. Something like "BlueCove failing to associate with Bluetooth device in Java"

Comment: It might be helpful to see the piece of code that's generating this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `java.io.IOException: Device not discovered`

Try going through the discovery and association stage.

Comment: How can i do that?sorry i dint understand.

Comment: No idea how to do it using Bluecove (I'm a bluez man), consult the API's!